# GTK in C: Segmentation Fault when using key-release or key-press

Tags: c, gtk

For context, I'm trying to make a program that changes stylized label text in response to some physical inputs on a beaglebone black (eg. get a signal, if high/low, show this text). In lieu of those inputs, which I don't have access to right now, I decided to use key-release as a substitute.

I've been basing my code off of this [combo-box tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtkwidgetsII/), which changes label text based on the text of a combo-box selection. I've modified that code to use stylized text as in the code below.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void combo_selected(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer window) {

  gchar *text = g_strjoin(NULL,"<span font='48' weight='bold' color='#DDDDDD'>",gtk_combo_box_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widget)),"</span>",NULL); //label text, uses pango markup
  gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(window), text);
  g_free(text);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *hbox;
  GtkWidget *vbox;
  GtkWidget *combo;
  GtkWidget *label;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GtkComboBox");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 0);
  vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 15);

  combo = gtk_combo_box_new_text();
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Ubuntu");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Arch");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Fedora");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Mint");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Gentoo");
  gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "Debian");

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), combo, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gchar *str = "<span font='48' weight='bold' color='#DDDDDD'>Not Initialized</span>"; //label text, uses pango markup
  label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
  gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), str); //add pango str to label

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), vbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(combo), "changed", 
        G_CALLBACK(combo_selected), (gpointer) label);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

That works, however when attempting to use a key-release or key-press instead of the combo box options, I get a segmentation fault. Below is the further-modified code (with some things commented out).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void fpcheck(GtkWidget *window, gpointer lbl) {
  gchar *text = "<span font='48' weight='bold' color='#DDDDDD'>Press index finger firmly on sensor.</span>";
  gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(lbl), text);

  //sleep(2); //placeholder -> fp detection

  //text = "<span font='48' weight='bold' color='#DDDDDD'>Fingerprint recognized!</span>";
  //gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(lbl), text);
  g_free(text);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window; //main window
  GtkWidget *align; //alignment settings
  GtkWidget *lbl; //text
  GdkColor color = {0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}; //window color

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); //init window
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER); //window pos on screen
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 480); //window size
  //gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE); //user cant resize
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"User Display"); //window title
  gtk_widget_modify_bg(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color); //set color to window
  align = gtk_alignment_new(.5,.5,0,0); //x,y alignment
  lbl = gtk_label_new(NULL); //label init

  gchar *str = "<span font='48' weight='bold' color='#DDDDDD'>Not Initialized</span>"; //label text, uses pango markup
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(align), lbl); //add label to alignment
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), align); //add label to window
  gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(lbl), str); //add pango str to label

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(fpcheck), (gpointer) lbl); //calls fpcheck to change label     

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window); //build the window all at once

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the `gtk_label_set_markup` line and `g_free(text)` line in `fpcheck`, there's no error but it doesn't do anything, of course. From looking at other online resources, I think this error is being cause by trying to access the `GTK_LABEL(lbl)` because of the first argument in `fpcheck` being incorrect, but thats just a guess and I don't know what I'd put there instead. In the example, it's just "Widget," referring to the combo-box, I think, since it gets the text from the selected option.

On that note, I tried removing that argument, and now instead of a segmentation error, I get the following error without even pressing/releasing.

```
(test:6698): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkWindow' to 'GtkLabel'

(test:6698): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_label_set_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

I did a few gdb backtraces, but none of them seem to be particularly helpful. If anyone wants 'em, I can post them.

Any ideas on the problems I'm having?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[key-release-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-release-event) handler has this signature

```
gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

Your fpcheck() needs to look like that.

It's easier to find problems like this early if you learn the habit of doing e.g. `g_assert (GTK_IS_LABEL (user_data))` as the first thing in every handler where the userdata definitely always has to be a label.

Comment: That did it. Just added a *widget and *event. Thanks! g_free(text) gives a pointer error now, but I'm not sure I even need it there.

Comment: text is a string literal and does not need to be freed. Only free what you allocate (or what a library call like `g_strjoin()` in your first example allocates).  .